# How to get current date in workflows (Dynamics CRM 2016)

Tags: dynamics-crm, crm, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-crm-2016

I would ask about how to get current date in workflows.?

For example:-

I have field called (Inspection Date) I would like to compare this filed if it equal current date then go into the process.

I will create Wait Condition waiting until current date = Inspection date then will do my process .

How to get current date in workflow.?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To answer the OP's question about how to get the current date in the workflow, the short answer is that you can't. As Henk van Boeijen has described, it is possible to get the current date in some of the individual steps however.

Where I work we have implemented a very basic custom workflow activity that simply returns the current date and time.

```
public class CurrentDateWorkflow : CodeActivity
{
    protected override void Execute(CodeActivityContext executionContext)
    {
        try
        {
            // Create the context and tracing service
            IExecutionContext context = executionContext.GetExtension<IExecutionContext>();
            IOrganizationServiceFactory serviceFactory = executionContext.GetExtension<IOrganizationServiceFactory>();
            IOrganizationService service = serviceFactory.CreateOrganizationService(context.UserId);
            ITracingService tracingService = executionContext.GetExtension<ITracingService>();
            if (tracingService == null)
                throw new InvalidPluginExecutionException("Failed to retrieve tracing service.");

            tracingService.Trace("Entered CurrentDateWorkflow.Execute(), Activity Instance Id: {0}, Workflow Instance Id: {1}",
                executionContext.ActivityInstanceId,
                executionContext.WorkflowInstanceId);

            var DatePartOnly = InputDatePartOnly.Get(executionContext);

            // Set output parameters
            if (DatePartOnly)
                CurrentDate.Set(executionContext, DateTime.UtcNow.Date);
            else
                CurrentDate.Set(executionContext, DateTime.UtcNow);

            // All done
            tracingService.Trace("CurrentDateWorkflow.Execute() Complete. Activity Instance Id: {0}, Workflow Instance Id: {1}",
                executionContext.ActivityInstanceId,
                executionContext.WorkflowInstanceId);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new InvalidPluginExecutionException(String.Format("An error occurred in the {0} plug-in.",
                    this.GetType().ToString()),
                    ex);
        }
    }

    [Output("Current Date")]
    public OutArgument<DateTime> CurrentDate { get; set; }

    [Input("Date Only")]
    [Default("False")]
    public InArgument<bool> InputDatePartOnly { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot for your answer, you mean there is no way I can do it, but in custom workflow.?  Thanks again .

Answer (score 2):

In window "Specify Condition" select field "Inspection Date" with condition "Is Greater Than or Equal To". In the Form Assistant expand picklist "Look for", select under "Local Values" the option "Process". In the box below the picklist "Execution Time" is displayed. Select it and you are done.

Comment: I tried this solution but unfortunately it didn't work. thanks a lot for your helping :) .

Comment: No, the execution time refers to the first execution of the process, and the wait condition does not take the current time into account.